# Using Functions to Pass an Array

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

- Hi, i am using a Function for the first time for my 2-D Array and so far i have been told it is right but i am having a problem with the 'For Loop'.
- Specifically repeating the printed statement and numbers until the array is full, and also shows the specific array you are filling. (As the image shows).

This only prints 1 statement with 1 Array, whilst 4 numbers afterwards.. How could i get each number printed after each statement? I have tried the only way i know which made it worse.
[Incorrectly Looped printed statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWaIQ.jpg)

Code below:

```
void DisplayArray(int a[2][2]);
int main()
{
    int a[2][2], i, j, k;
    /*Counter variables for the loop*/
    printf ("***** Functions ***** \n");
    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)  
        printf("\n Enter numeric values for each Array [%d] [%d]: \n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    DisplayArray(a);
    return 0;
}
void DisplayArray(int a[2][2])
{
    int i, j;
    /*Displaying Array elements*/
    printf("\n The 2-D Array contains : \n");
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)
            printf("%d \n" , a[i][j]);/*[i] name of 1 Array - [j] name of 2 Array*/
            if(j==2)
                printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Since you're using this type all over the place, it's time for a `typedef`.

Comment: Use curly braces.

Comment: what's the problem? You want it printed as a 2x2 box instead of one number per line?

Comment: @yano That is basically right, i want the Printf statement to print the number you entered - looped until the array is full. Then print out all the entered numbers into a Grid.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`  for the functions: `printf()` and `scanf()`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code contains several repitions of the 'magic' number 2.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (`for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to properly define the scope of the inner `for` loops.

The lines

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    for(j=0; j<2; j++)  
    printf("\n Enter numeric values for each Array [%d] [%d]: \n", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
```

are equivalent to:

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    for(j=0; j<2; j++)
       printf("\n Enter numeric values for each Array [%d] [%d]: \n", i, j);

// Outside of both the for loops. 
scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
```

The indent expresses the intent to a human reader but not to the computer.

You need to use:

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
   for(j=0; j<2; j++)
   {  // Add
      printf("\n Enter numeric values for each Array [%d] [%d]: \n", i, j);
      scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
   } // Add
```

To make the code more readable add an explicit scope for the outer `for` loops too.

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
{  // Add
   for(j=0; j<2; j++)
   {  // Add
      printf("\n Enter numeric values for each Array [%d] [%d]: \n", i, j);
      scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
   } // Add
} // Add
```

Make similar changes to the other loops.

Comment: Ah okay, i understand what your saying now i think i realised what i did wrong with the Brackets completely missing i am going to try and amend this on my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops are probably not acting as you intended, because without the curly braces, they will only act on the first statement.

```
void DisplayArray(int a[2][2]);
int main()
{
    int a[2][2], i, j, k;
    /*Counter variables for the loop*/
    printf ("***** Functions ***** \n");
    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            printf("\n Enter numeric values for each Array [%d] [%d]: \n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    DisplayArray(a);
    return 0;
}
void DisplayArray(int a[2][2])
{
    int i, j;
    /*Displaying Array elements*/
    printf("\n The 2-D Array contains : \n");
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d \n" , a[i][j]);/*[i] name of 1 Array - [j] name of 2 Array*/
            if(j==2)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking to myself whether or not the brackets were/are needed within the Function(s) so i will give this a go. Thanks.

Comment: The curly braces create a "code block" that basically count as one statement. Additionally, any variables you create inside a block only have scope inside that block, meaning that you can't use them after.

Comment: regarding this code block: `if(j==2)
                printf("\n");`   this code block is inside the loop.  the loop exits when j is 2, so this code will never be executed,  suggest elimination of the 'if()` statement and move the body of the `if()` to immediately after the closing brace of that loop

Comment: one of the tenets of good coding practice is to minimize the 'scope' of variables.  Therefore, the variable 'i' and 'j' should be declared inside the initializer parameter of the associated 'for()' statement.  Similar to: `for( int i=0; i<2; i++)`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some curly braces. Change to this:

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
        printf("\n Enter numeric values for each Array [%d] [%d]: \n", i, j);
        scanf(" %d", &a[i][j]);
        DisplayArray(a);
    }
```

and

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
        printf("%d \n" , a[i][j]);
        if(j==2)
            printf("\n");
    }
```

Also, note that `if(j==2)` will never evaluate to true. When j is equal to 2, the loop is over. You should change this to 1. I would also suggest to remove `\n` in the innermost printf statement.

Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void DisplayArray(int a[2][2]);
int main()
{
    int a[2][2], i, j, k;
    /*Counter variables for the loop*/
    printf ("***** Functions ***** \n");
    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
        for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
            printf("\n Enter numeric values for each Array [%d] [%d]: \n", i, j);
            scanf(" %d", &a[i][j]);
            DisplayArray(a);
        }
    return 0;
}
void DisplayArray(int a[2][2])
{
    int i, j;
    /*Displaying Array elements*/
    printf("\n The 2-D Array contains : \n");
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
        for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
            printf("%d " , a[i][j]);/*[i] name of 1 Array - [j] name of 2 Array*/
            if(j==1)
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```